# Using Spring HibernateTemplate. How to delete by Id?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

For work with database, my class extends `HibernateDaoSupport` class and inside the methods I'm using Spring `HibernateTemplate`.

So, for delete a row in database I use this method:

```
public void delete(MyObject obj) {
    getHibernateTemplate().delete(obj);
}
```

all ok!

But, at this moment I'm trying to implement a method that can delete a row based on id:

```
public void delete(final long id) {
    // some code here
}
```

And I can't find some `HibernateTemplate` method like this:
`getHibernateTemplate().remove(id)`

What is a good solution for me in this case?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

delete using particular id,

```
public void delete(long id)
{
    Session session ;
    MyObject myObject ;

    session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    myObject = (MyObject)session.load(MyObject.class,id);
    session.delete(myObject);

    //This makes the pending delete to be done
    session.flush() ;

}
```

Also consider encapuslate this methods in try/catch/finally and log the error as needed

Comment: This seem to be the most elegant solution (without using sql/hql queries), but it does seem rather inefficiente as it appears to fecth the whole object in order to delete it. Is that the case? I if so, what can be done?

Comment: If id is not exists, the `myObject` will be null, and `delete()` may cause error?

Comment: @NingLee yes, you get an exception due to load considers that the object exists. If you want to avoid such exception use `get` rather than `load`

Answer (score 11):

Another alternative is:

```
public void deleteById(Class clazz,Integer id) {
    String hql = "delete " + clazz.getName() + " where id = :id";
    Query q = session.createQuery(hql).setParameter("id", id);
    q.executeUpdate();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

As you mentioned, there s not such method in HibernateTemplate. You can do the following,

```
hibernateTemplate.delete(hibernateTemplate.get(Class,Id));
```

Comment: Wow, this takes care of cascade delete too !!

Answer (score 6):

You can also use below method:

```
public void deleteById(Class clazz,Integer id) {
    hibernateTemplate.bulkUpdate("delete from "+clazz.getName()+" where id="+id);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple solution by creating an object and setting only the ID:

```
Product product = new Product();
product.setId(37);
session.delete(product);
```

The drawback of this simple solution is that it doesn’t remove the associated instances.
If you have some attribute (another entity related) of the product to be deleted, you will need to load the product before.

```
 Serializable id = new Long(17); 
 Object persistentInstance = session.load(Product.class, id); 
 if (persistentInstance != null) 
 {
   session.delete(persistentInstance); 
 }
```

This will issue (if you have an attribute table in cascade) a delete on the children attributes.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Delete<T>(int id)
{
    var entity = this.GetSession().Load<T>(id);
    this.GetSession().Delete(entity);
}
```